# Automapper not ForMember not mapping (Saying property is unmapped)

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using Automapper 6.2.2.0, and trying to map from an entity object to a DTO, with different property names.

I am getting the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>
> ## ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> CompanyInfo -> OwnerDto (Destination member list) Db.CompanyInfo ->
>   TransferObjects.OwnerDto (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: Name

My mapping looks like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CompanyInfo, OwnerDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));
```

My OwnerDto class:

```
public class OwnerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my CompanyInfo Class:

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping:

```
var results = Mapper.Map<List<CompanyInfo>,List <OwnerDto>>(data);
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Initializer:

```
public static class AutomapperMaps {
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap();

    cfg.CreateMap<CompanyInfo, OwnerDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));

    // There are more mappings like the user one above. Those are all working fine.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is between `CreateMap` and `Mapper.Map`?

Comment: Are you sure your `CreateMap` is running before you attempt to call `Map`?

Comment: Yeah I am sure, if I change the OwnerDto.Name to CompanyName, then the mapping works fine. Unfotunately I need to deliver this as Name, for a reason that I cannot control

Comment: Are you sure you use Mapper.Initialize?

Comment: Yeah, see my previous comment.

Comment: Can you please post the whole Mapper.Initialize here?

Comment: @h3li0s It works => https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZhNxFt

Comment: @h3li0s So how AutomapperMaps is called?

Comment: `AutomapperMaps ` this class is not valid. Generally it looks like you are trying to Map before initialize

Comment: Thanks for your support, I've found the issue, it was a problem in my code base, trying to initialize two different Automappers. After removing that, it started to work.

Comment: Your questions helped me doubt my code :)